# Defining a set connotatively or denotatively.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, definition, foundations, philosophy

> “It is said that a set can be defined connotatively or denotatively. Which of these terms applies to the definition by roster and which to the definition by a defining sentence?”- p. 137, *[Elements of Modern Math](https://books.google.com/books/about/Elements_of_Modern_Mathematics.html?id=gzdixAEACAAJ)*, K. O. May.

The author is asking me to match the words *connotative* and *denotative* to the roster notation $\{\,\}$ or to a a set designated by a defining sentence $\{ x \mid f(x) \}$. I say that the roster notation is connotative and a defining sentence of a set is denotative. The former lists the elements of a set, and generally what could belong in that set, while the latter defines a set, kind of, I suppose as a dictionary does.

Is this correct? Any elucidating thoughts are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, it is the other way round.

The *connotation* (also known as *intension*) of a set is its description or defining properties, i.e., what is true about the elements of a set.

The *denotation* (also known as *extension*) of a set is its content, i.e., the list of its elements.

A set is totally defined by its denotation, and the same denotation (i.e., the same set) can have several connotations. For instance, the set $\{2, 3\}$ can be described as:

1. the set of natural numbers greater than $1$ and less than $4$;
2. the set of the first two prime numbers.

For an infinite set, it is not possible to explicitly give its denotation (since the list of its elements is infinite), the only way to identify it is connotative.

Comment: Although often a pseudo-roster form is given for countable sets in which there is an obvious pattern,  i.e. $\mathbb N=\{0,1,2,3,...\}$

Comment: @Alan - Sure, but this is not a formal, rigorous or unambiguous definition for that set.

Comment: Agreed, thus the common English use of "pseudo", as opposed to, say,  Fuzzy Pseudo Quasi Metric Spaces.   When I came across those by accident, I was sure some topologist was just having fun with the names...https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/188298342.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the clarifying response!